# JBoss claims that my persistence unit is installed already. But the server just started

Tags: hibernate, jboss

JBoss claims that my persistence unit is installed already. But the server just started! Since there's only one persistence.xml file in the .war, I can't see what the problem is.

> 17:53:14,484 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to
>   Real:
>   name=vfsfile:/C:/clicktime/inspirion/clicktime/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1328796645796/deploy/clicktime5.war/
>   state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying:
>   persistence.unit:unitName=#clicktime5
>   
> … 
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   persistence.unit:unitName=#clicktime5 is already installed.

**Update**:

I see something interesting now. Mojarra gets run twice: once for /clicktime, once for /clicktime5, as if I'd be deploying two different things on my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most probably a human error. JBoss does not deploy anything twice unless they are two difference instances. You probably have another deployment with that name already. Take a good look at the server.log to find more detail.

Comment: That was precisely what was happening. I deployed the same project twice: once thru Eclipse, and once as a .war file in the deploy directory.